# Question on Predicates and Quantifiers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, propositional-logic

I am reading from *"Discrete Mathematics and Its applications"* by Kenneth H. Rosen, 7th edition. Consider the **highlighted part** in the following example taken from the same book:

> **Question** Use predicates and quantifiers to express the system specifications “Every mail message larger
>   than one megabyte will be compressed” and “If a user is active, at least one network link will
>   be available.”
>
> **Solution:** Let S(m, y) be “Mail message m is larger than y megabytes,” where the variable x has
>   the domain of all mail messages and the variable y is a positive real number, and let C(m) denote
>   “Mail message m will be compressed.” Then the specification “Every mail message larger than
>   one megabyte will be compressed” can be represented as ∀m(S(m, 1) → C(m)).
>   Remember the rules of
>   precedence for quantifiers
>   and logical connectives!
>   Let A(u) represent “User u is active,” where the variable u has the domain of all users,
>   let S(n, x) denote “Network link n is in state x,” where n has the domain of all network
>   links and x has the domain of all possible states for a network link. Then the specification
>   “If a user is active, at least one network link will be available” can be represented by
>
> **∃uA(u) → ∃nS(n, available)**.

"Existential quantifier" **∃u** is used here, So I think, it should be **∃uA(u)∧ ∃nS(n, available)** in place of **∃uA(u) → ∃nS(n, available)**.

Generally, we use 'implication' with 'universal quantifier' as shown in **∀m(S(m, 1) → C(m))**.

Please correct me, if I am wrong.

Comment: Can you replace the image by text?

Comment: Updated, let me know if i need to make any other changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The meaning of
$$ \exists u A(u) \land \exists n S(n,\text{available}) $$
is "there exists an active user, and there exists a network link which is available". The conditioning is missing here.

If $P = \exists u A(u)$ and $Q = \exists n S(n,\text{available})$, then we are trying to model "if $P$ then $Q$", whose formal form is $P \rightarrow Q$, whereas your answer is $P \land Q$.

In particular, if there *doesn't* exist an active user, then $P \land Q$ is always false, whereas $P \to Q$ is always true.

Comment: if there is no "active user" won't still it be true?

Comment: It can be true or false. The difference between what you wrote and the correct answer is exactly the difference between $P \land Q$ and $P \rightarrow Q$.

Comment: my doubt is “If a user is active, at least one network link will be available.” 
if there is no active user, then it should give truth value as "false" but P→Q always gives true if the premise is false. or why can't we use
∀uA(u) → ∃nS(n, available)?

Comment: The phrase "If P then Q" has exactly the same semantics as $P\to Q$.

Comment: yes, but why did author not use "Universal Quantifier" ∀ in second part of the question like first part?

Comment: In the statement "“If a user is active, at least one network link will be available,” P represents "[some] user is active", and Q represents "at least one network link [is] available". Both are existential statements: there *exists* a user which is active, there *exists* a network link which is available.

Comment: @ManuThakur Where did you get the idea "_Generally, we use 'implication' with 'universal quantifier'_"?